# Matching [0-9] on regexp without {}

Tags: regex, tcl

As I was asked to match the string  "[0-9]" (please note i dont mean to match number 0 to 9)
I used

```
set a {[0-9]}
regexp  {\[0-9\]} $a out
```

which works perfectly., But anyway In an interview i was asked to not use {} to enclose the pattern and to do it alternatively with "" or something else

```
regexp  "\[0-9\]" $a out
```

But strangely when i use "" i can only match only 0

Is there anyway it can be done without {} in regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to use `regexp` to do that. You could use string methods, such as `string match` which uses glob matching:

```
string match {*[0-9]*} $a
```

`*` will match anything, it's a wildcard in glob matching.

Or you could use `string first` with `expr`, which basically returns 1 if the returned index is above -1 (i.e. the `[0-9]` is in the string `$a`) or 0 otherwise (i.e. there is no `[0-9]` in the string `$a`):

```
expr {[string index {[0-9]} $a] > -1}
```

Anyway, if you really want a regex, you'll have some escaping to do:

```
regexp {\[0-9\]} $a out
```

Note that you won't need the `$out` since you are looking for an exact match of something that cannot change, so you might as well use `regexp {\[0-9\]} $a`

Or use a syntax which tells `regexp` to treat the string literally:

```
regexp {***=[0-9]} $a
```

or

```
regexp {(?q)[0-9]} $a
```

Where `***=` and `(?q)` tells `regexp` to treat the following characters as literal ones.

You can learn more about the re syntax [on this man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm).

---

> But strangely when I use "" I can only match only 0

That's because what you are passing to the `regexp` engine is `[0-9]`. This is because the `\[` and `\]` are being substituted before passing the expression to `regexp`. So you are actually having the expression `[0-9]` being passed, which will match any single digit.

Comment: Btw, if you are told that you should not use `{}`, that's pretty cruel, because using `""`, you will have to use *three* backslashes: `regexp "\\\[0-9\\\]" $a` The first two will make a literal backslash, and the second will make a literal `[`, which then passes `\[0-9\]` to the regexp, which then works as you expect it to. Though you can still use `***=` or `(?q)` and single backslashes like `regexp "***=\[0-9\]" $a` or `regexp "(?q)\[0-9\]" $a`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I have been looking for

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl, `{`…`}` is *just a quoting mechanism.* You never need it, but it can be really annoying to write code without it. Let's write without any quotes at all:

```
regexp \\\[0-9\\\] $a out
```

Notice that we've got triple backslashes in there, because we want one backslash for the RE engine (which prevents the `[` being a character set) and one backslash for each character of of `\[` (which stops the Tcl basic syntax engine from interpreting things). We could put double quotes around it; all they really do is stop the basic syntax engine from detecting the end of the word until it hits the matching close of the double quotes, but we're not using any whitespace at all in the RE so it doesn't matter. It's conventional to put double quotes around things that people think of as strings for highlighting purposes, but Tcl doesn't really work that way.

In fact, one of Tcl's main claims to fame is just how few special syntax forms it really has, and how it applies them consistently to everything. For example, we can write procedures entirely without the use of braces:

```
proc foo "a b" "
    for set\\ i\\ \\\$a \\\$i\\ <\\ \\\$b incr\\ i puts\\ \\\$i...
"
```

That's code that works just fine; it's functionally identical to:

```
proc foo {a b} {
    for {set i $a} {$i < $b} {incr i} {puts $i...}
}
```

But which is the clearer one to write? The easier one to write? I think the answer is self-evident! Know that you never need to use braces, but for goodness' sake use braces in reality!

Comment: Getting the backslashes right in that awful chunk of brace-free code was not fun! What's more, the deeper you nest the code, the less fun it becomes…

Comment: Thanks Donal, Even I thought the same why people ask to replace braces when its regexp correctly doing it purpose. But now I realise it is intended to know how regexp works ., I thought basic tcl syntax required  one backslash to prevent substitution but totally unaware of regex engine ., thanks again